# Use `for` in `print()` will give a generator on Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Why and how does it works? For example I'm writing a list comprehension like this:

```
>>> a = (10, 30, 20)
>>> print([q for q in a])
[10, 30, 20]
```

At now, if I remove the `[]`, this will also work, but:

```
>>> a = (10, 30, 20)
>>> print(q for q in a)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fe527d1dca8>
```

Does Python make a generator here? And if I do this without `print()`:

```
>>> a = (10, 30, 20)
>>> b = q for q in a

File "<input>", line 1
  b = q for q in a
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm thinking about because `(q for q in a)` will make a generator, but that's impossible, however I'm not using two pair of `()` like:

```
>>> a = (10, 30, 20)
>>> print((q for q in a)) # here is two pair of `()`
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fe527d1dca8>
```

Comment: If you want to print the items, rather than the generator object that yields them, try `print(*(q for q in a))`. The `*` unpacks the items as arguments to the function. (Though, for this particular generator you could just do `print(*a)` and be done with it.)

Comment: It works exactly the same as any other function , sum,  max, min ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does Python make a generator here?

Yes. Quoting official documentation of [Generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions),

> The parentheses can be omitted on calls with only one argument.

---

Note that this is the only exception from the actual syntax

```
generator_expression ::=  "(" expression comp_for ")"
```

So, when you did

```
b = q for q in a
```

Python was not able to parse it, as it is not a valid Python expression. That is why you were getting a `SyntaxError`.

---

If you actually wanted to print all the elements from the generator expression, you can unpack the result of it to the `print` function, as suggested by Blckknght, like this

```
>>> a = (10, 30, 20)
>>> print(*(q for q in a))
10 30 20
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.x, print is a function.

Normally, when you try to create a generator expression and store it in a variable (or in some other places), you need to enclose it in `()` . Example -

```
b = (q for q in a)
```

But if you are passing a generator expression to a function as a psotional argument, **and it is the only argument** , then you do not need the enclosing `()` .

It is explained in the [PEP 0289 -](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#id16)

> if a function call has a single positional argument, it can be a generator expression without extra parentheses, but in all other cases you have to parenthesize it.

Or [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) (As also given by the other answer) -

> The parentheses can be omitted on calls with only one argument.

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses aren't what make a generator, just like they aren't what make a `tuple`. Something like `return 2,3` will `return` the `tuple` of `(2, 3)`:

```
>>> def f():
...     return 2,3
...
>>> f()
(2, 3)
>>> type(f())
<class 'tuple'>
```

You can make a `tuple` with a single character with just the comma:

```
>>> 2,
(2,)
>>> a = 2,
>>> type(a)
<class 'tuple'>
```

You only need the parentheses when they provide disambiguation for the syntax, such as `[(a,b) for a,b in zip([1,2], [1,2])]`.

```
>>> [a,b for a,b in zip([1,2], [1,2])]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [a,b for a,b in zip([1,2], [1,2])]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> [(a,b) for a,b in zip([1,2], [1,2])]
[(1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Regarding the `print()` call, if you include the parentheses you can then use the `*` operator to unpack the generator:

```
>>> a = (10, 30, 20)
>>> print([q for q in a])
[10, 30, 20]
>>> print(q for q in a)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000003B84B88>
>>> print(*(q for q in a))
10 30 20
>>> print(*(q for q in a if q<25))
10 20
>>> print(*a)
10 30 20
```

This occasionally saves some typing.